# Excel VBA - Allow Digits in String

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this function to restrict users from entering special characters but I am also looking to allow users to be able to enter only 2 digits (should they want) together with letters. Is this possible?

```
Public Function IsAlpha(strValue As String) As Boolean
    IsAlpha = strValue Like WorksheetFunction.Rept("[-a-zA-Z ]", Len(strValue)) And _
       Len(strValue) = Len(Application.Trim(strValue))
End Function
```

Comment: The best option is regex. I remember you asking a similar question a while back. Do you also have conditions as to whether the text input from the user can start with a digit or a hyphen?

Comment: yes it should start with a letter only... I believe regex needs a special reference in VBA which I am trying to avoid

Comment: Are you open to late binding (would not require reference library preloaded) regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version without regular expressions:

```
Public Function IsAlpha(strValue As String) As Boolean
    IsAlpha = strValue Like "[-a-zA-Z]" & _
        WorksheetFunction.Rept("[-a-zA-Z 0-9]", Len(strValue) - 1) _
        And _
        Len(strValue) = Len(Application.Trim(strValue)) _
        And _
        Not strValue Like "*[0-9][0-9][0-9]*"
End Function
```

It looks for a string starting with something else than a number, followed by letters and numbers. After that it checks that there aren't three consecutive numbers.

Having that said - don't do like this. This is the very purpose of regular expresssions.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to load the regex reference library, you can use late binding.

```
Public Function IsAlpha(strValue As String) As Boolean
    Dim rgx As Object
    Set rgx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    With rgx
        .Global = False
        .Pattern = "^[A-Z]*[0-9]?[A-Z]*[0-9]?[A-Z]*$"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = False
        IsAlpha = .Test(strValue)
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: ok this seems to work for me provided it is compatible with Excel 2007 and onwards

Comment: As long as you don't need to run it on Mac